# Счетчик для share-кнопки facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook

Здравствуйте. В своем проекте я использую самописные share-кнопки. До недавнего времени для получения счетчика facebook я использовал следующую конструкцию:

```
var counterUrl = 'https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+total_count+FROM+link_stat+WHERE+url%3D%22' + encodeURIComponent(url) + '%22&callback=?';
$.getJSON(counterUrl, function (response) { ... });
```

Теперь же facebook говорит, о том, что данный метод устарел, возвращая на запрос ошибку:

```
(#12) fql is deprecated for versions v2.1 and higher
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой иной метод получения числа поделившихся ссылкой существует?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На текущий момент работающий способ без лишних полей в ответе:
`https://graph.facebook.com/?id= + YOUR_URL + &fields=share{share_count}`